FFMPEG command to merge audio, video and BGM files for a specific final video file
Given:

A video file (Video1)
An audio file (Audio1)
A background music (BGM) file (BGM1)

Task:
Create a new video file (OutputVideo) with the following
specifications:  
a. Video Track:  Identical to the video track of Video
b. Combination of Audio1 and BGM1: Overlay Phase: Audio1 and BGM1 (at 30% volume) play simultaneously for the duration of Audio1. 
c. BGM Phase: BGM1 continues to play at 100% volume from the end of Audio1 until the end of Video1. 

Constraints:

OutputVideo should have the same duration as Video1.

Current ffmpeg command:
ffmpeg -y -i videoPath -i audioPath -i bgmPath -filter_complex "[2:a]aloop=loop=-1:size=2e9[bgm_repeated];[bgm_repeated]volume=0.3[bgm_low];[1:a][bgm_low]amix=inputs=2:duration=first[mixed];[2:a]volume=1[bgm_full];[2:a]atrim=start=%.2f:end=%.2f[bgm_trimmed];[mixed][bgm_trimmed]acrossfade=d=2:c1=tri:c2=exp[audio_mid];[bgm_full][audio_mid]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[audio_final]" -map 0:v -map "[audio_final]" -c:v copy -shortest finalVideoPath
This doesn't seem to work.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What exactly "doesn't seem to work"? Is the length wrong? You need to be specific here.
